# Problem not visible item in Honor 6x (Recyclerview with StaggeredGridLayoutManager)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, adapter, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I am using **Recyclerview** whose layer is **StaggeredGridLayoutManager**. The problem is that in most phones the items are displayed but in **Honor 6x phones** the items are not displayed but they can be clicked.

**I set the items rotationY:180 to show right to left.**

I even used **GridLayoutManager** but it still has the same problem.

**Screenshot on all phones**
[image]

**On the Honor 6x phone**
[image]

**Recyclerview Widget**

```
    public class AutoFitGridRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager;
    private int columnWidth = -1;

    public AutoFitGridRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public AutoFitGridRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public AutoFitGridRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            // list the attributes we want to fetch
            // columnWidth is what GridView uses, so we use it too
            int[] attrsArray = {
                    android.R.attr.columnWidth
            };

            TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);

            //retrieve the value of the 0 index, which is columnWidth
            columnWidth = array.getDimensionPixelSize(0, -1);
            array.recycle();
        }

        manager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(AppController.NumberColumnAutoFitForRecyclerViewForGridList(120), 1);
        setLayoutManager(manager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

        if (columnWidth > 0) {
            //The spanCount will always be at least 1
            int spanCount = Math.max(1, getMeasuredWidth() / columnWidth);
            manager.setSpanCount(spanCount);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

in Activity layout

```
<com.mrsanad.Application.Widgets.AutoFitGridRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/gridMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:rotationY="180" />
```

**in item layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bRow"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rotationY="180">

    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
        app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:mrl_rippleDuration="350"
        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
        app:mrl_rippleRoundedCorners="100dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/layoutTitle">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:padding="12dp" />

                <com.mrsanad.Application.Widgets.BadgeTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCount"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="0.5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/SmallTextSize" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                <com.mrsanad.Application.Widgets.PersianTextViewBold
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/Gray"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/SmallTextSize" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**in Adapter java**

```
package Adapters.ActMain;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.mrsanad.Application.Utility.Variable;
import com.mrsanad.Network.Models.Response.Home.GetHome.Menu;
import com.mrsanad.R;
import com.mrsanad.Application.Utility.AppController;
import com.mrsanad.Application.Widgets.BadgeTextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class AdpMenu extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdpMenu.ViewMenu> {

    private List<Menu> Items = new ArrayList<>();

    public AdpMenu() {
    }

    public void AddItems(List<Menu> items) {
        Items.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Menu GetItem(int pos) {
        return Items.get(pos);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewMenu onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(AppController.Context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_home_menu, parent, false);
        return new ViewMenu(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewMenu holder, int position) {
        Menu item = GetItem(position);

        holder.tvTitle.setText(item.NameFa);
        AppController.SetPicUrl(holder.imgIcon, item.ImagePath, 0, "");
        holder.tvCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Items.size();
    }

    public void Clear() {
        Items.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewMenu extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.imgIcon)
        ImageView imgIcon;
        @BindView(R.id.tvTitle)
        TextView tvTitle;
        @BindView(R.id.layoutTitle)
        RelativeLayout layoutTitle;
        @BindView(R.id.tvCount)
        BadgeTextView tvCount;

        public ViewMenu(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

            tvCount.setStrokeWidth(1);
            tvCount.setStrokeColor(AppController.Context.getString(R.color.White));
            tvCount.setSolidColor(AppController.Context.getString(R.color.Orange));
        }
    }
}
```

**in Java Actvity**

```
@BindView(R.id.gridMenu)
    RecyclerView gridMenu;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_main);

        AdpMenu AdpMenu = new AdpMenu();
    gridMenu.setAdapter(AdpMenu);

       AdpMenu.AddItems(\\All items list);

    }
```

Comment: what android version honor 6x??

Comment: Android 6.0 (Marshmallow), upgradable to 7.0 (Nougat).

**Is it important?**@JavadDehban

Comment: Solved this issue?

Comment: no @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to [**`ConstraintLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout).

> ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a
> flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to
> RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to
> relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's
> more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android
> Studio's Layout Editor.

You can use [**`SDP`**](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) instead of <s>**dp**</s>. This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

Your value will be

```
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
```

### FYI

You can use [**`Glide`**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).It is an Image Loader Library for Android developed by bumptech and is a library that is recommended by Google.

> Glide is a fast and efficient open source media management and image
> loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and
> disk caching, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use
> interface.

```
RequestManager requestManager = Glide.with(contextObj);
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = requestManager.load(item.ImagePath);
requestBuilder.into(holder.imgIcon);
```

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you read the question?  My question is that it does not display the item at all, but you can click on the item

Comment: @MohammadSalmanian Show your `AppController.SetPicUrl` method. You can use GLIDE

Comment: I use Picasso and it does not display TextView either.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are loading the image resources from drawable. In that case, you should check which version your Honor 6x is currently running? and also check if the resources you are loading are in proper screen density size folders as well.